# How to solve , Even loop delay (not real time) When fast hover `in, out , in , out , in, out , in , out`?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to solve , Even loop delay (not real time) When fast hover `in, out , in , out , in, out , in , out` ?

When i fast hover `in , out , in , out , in , out , in , out , in , out , in , out , in , out`

Even will show loop delay.

I want to set even to,  if i fast hover `in , out , in , out , in , out , in , out , in , out , in , out , in , out` Do not show even loop delay

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/peap/qw0xLn1k/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $("#111").hover(
        function(){
            var id = $(this).data("id");
            if(id!==undefined){
             $("#" + id).show();   
            }
            $(".outer").animate({top: '13px' , opacity: 1}, 100); 
            $(".inner").animate({top: '47px' , opacity: 1},100); 

        },function(){
            $(".outer").animate({top: '25px' , opacity: 0}, 100); 
            $(".inner").animate({top: '37px' , opacity: 0},100);                         
        });
});
```

you can see for example in http://www.fiverr.com/ , when you mouseover image heart it's will show real element not even loop .

Comment: You do the hokey-cokey

Comment: Thats what it's all about.

Comment: [`.stop()`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/)

Comment: Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/qw0xLn1k/1/

Comment: –  briosheje it's work , but not real time even completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [`stop()`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) any existing animations before queuing more:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $("#111").hover(
        function() {
            var id = $(this).data("id");

            if (id) {
                $("#" + id).show();   
            }

            $(".outer").stop().animate({top: '13px', opacity: 1}, 100); 
            $(".inner").stop().animate({top: '47px', opacity: 1}, 100); 
        }, function() {
            $(".outer").stop().animate({top: '25px', opacity: 0}, 100); 
            $(".inner").stop().animate({top: '37px', opacity: 0}, 100);                         
        });
});
```

If you can use them, though, CSS transitions might be more appropriate. For example, if `.inner` and `.outer` are children of `#111`:

```css
#111 .outer {
    /* … */
    opacity: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 25px;
    transition: all 0.1s ease;
}

#111 .inner {
    /* … */
    opacity: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 37px;
    transition: all 0.1s ease;
}

#111:hover .outer {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 13px;
}

#111:hover .inner {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 47px;
}
```

Comment: please give some fiddle .

Comment: @ดารกนารวดากาก: Oh, didn’t notice you had a fiddle. CSS transitions won’t work in that case. Anyways, all you have to do is paste `.stop()` in four places. http://jsfiddle.net/qw0xLn1k/3/

Comment: it ok , but not complete, you can see for example in http://www.fiverr.com/ , when you mouseover image heart it's will show real element not even loop . how they do that ?

Comment: @ดารกนารวดากาก: What do you mean by “loop”?

Comment: loop mean like when you mouseleave , all even will stop , not delay. ^^

Comment: @ดารกนารวดากาก: So you want to hide it immediately once the mouse leaves? Fiverr doesn’t do that.

Comment: yes correct , then how fiverr do ? i try to inspects element but i can not find code.

Comment: @ดารกนารวดากาก: I’m still not sure where you’re seeing the delay. Can you describe what you’re doing and what behaviour you’re talking about?

Comment: yes, you are correct, your fiddle are real time mouseleave ^^ thankyou.